# removing vs2012 messages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

In VS2012 i am getting many messages, not errors, just messages like the following

" Message2  Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'placeholder' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.    "

Since my doctypes are html5, even though they are asp:Textbox, that attribute is valid. Why am I getting these messages? Is there a setting I need to change in VS to remove these as they are nothing but annoying to look at.

Comment: You can control what is validated using Tools->Options->Text Editor->HTML. There may be a less drastic solution than hiding all validation messages, but that's the option I have selected and I can't say I miss it.

Comment: unfortunately I already have that set on html5

Comment: There's a checkbox underneath the dropdown (with "HTML 5") on the same screen. It says, "Show errors". That's what I have unchecked to remove unwanted warnings.

Comment: ty, I'll do it to remove the messages but that seems like a kludge. Certainly MSFT must have a way of validating these properly in VS

Comment: You would think so. Maybe someone else has a better answer.

Comment: Any solution ever found for this? The problem persists in VS2013.